# How do I copy picturedata from one image to another?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two image controls. I want to set one of the image controls to hold the same image as the other one. I need to do this in runtime, using VBA.

```
Me("Option" & RST![ItemNumber]).PictureData = Me("img" & intImage).PictureData
```

For some reason this line of code doesn't do the trick. It does not give errors, but instead leaves the picture control blank. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an Image control?

Comment: Yes I am using an Image control

Comment: Use Picture property instead of PictureData.

Comment: This gives the error: Microsoft Access can't open the file 'StaffCalendar16.ico'

Comment: So check if the file exists, you have required rights, and the path to the file.

Comment: The file does not exist, it's just an image that exists on the Access form. It's embedded.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792426/access-export-images-from-image-controls-in-forms

Comment: Well, I tested with an image that was set as Embedded in the Image control. However, the image does still exist externally. So I renamed the file and then code fails. So as @Sam suggests will have to export image to external location.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, not sure why Microsoft keeps making things harder. I'll give that a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Microsoft Access 2010 or newer, you can add the image to Access `Image Gallery`.

Once added to the gallery you can rename it there if you want.

This name you then can use to paste it to the `Picture` property of the image control to assign it to.

One advantage is that you can reference those images to many image controls, but they only use memory once for storage in the database.

The other advantage is, that you can assign them like this (without having the original file on the disk):

```
Image1.Picture = Image2.Picture
```