# Best way to export an Icon Image from Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have about 50 icon images (.ico) on an Access form, however I don't have them stored on a disk. I'd like to export them from Access onto a disk location.

I tried the suggested solution on this thread:

[Access - Export images from Image controls in forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792426/access-export-images-from-image-controls-in-forms][1])

I couldn't open the resulting file, probably because my images are (.ico) rather than (.png)

EDIT: I'm able to copy the icons into paint, save them as pngs, then use an online converter to convert them to icons. Pretty time consuming but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code blow.

It will save the content of all image controls of the provided form to files in the same folder.

Beware that some image controls contain 'strange' binary formats which maybe can't be displayed properly by every tool.

Also you would have to take care to assign a correct file extension after exporting yourself.

Place the code in a new module, then open the form in design view and call it like this: `SaveAllImageControls Forms("MyForm")`

```
Public Sub SaveAllImageControls(ByRef sourceForm As Form)
    Dim item As control
    For Each item In sourceForm.Controls: Do
        If item.ControlType <> acImage Then Exit Do
        If IsNull(item.PictureData) Then Exit Do

        Dim bArray() As Byte
        bArray = item.PictureData

        Dim filename As String
        filename = Application.CurrentDb.Name & "-" & sourceForm.Name & "-" & item.Name & ".binary"

        Dim fileNumber As Integer
        fileNumber = FreeFile

        Open filename For Binary As fileNumber
        Put fileNumber, , bArray
        Close fileNumber
    Loop While False: Next item
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to export all the ico files and then process them with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/). You can run something like

```
convert image.ico image.png
```

either as part of the code you linked to or as a plain one time call in a command prompt.